# How to write a bash script that dumps itself out to stdout (for use as a help file)?

Tags: bash

Sometimes I want a bash script that's mostly a help file. There are probably better ways to do things, but sometimes I want to just have a file called "awk_help" that I run, and it dumps my awk notes to the terminal.

How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution that works on Mac/Linux and works exactly as one would hope.

Just use the following as your "shebang" line, and it'll output everything from line 2 on down:

#### test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/tail -n+2
hi there
how are you
```

Running this gives you what you'd expect:

```
$ ./test.sh
hi there
how are you
```

and another possible solution - just use `less`, and that way your file will open in searchable gui

```
#!/usr/bin/less
```

and this way you can grep if for something too, e.g.

```
$ ./test.sh | grep something
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it can be done as pretty much a one liner, thanks to [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) for the suggestions!

Just put the following at the top of the file, and you're done

`cat "$BASH_SOURCE" | grep -v EZREMOVEHEADER`

So for my `awk_help` example, it'd be:

```
cat "$BASH_SOURCE" | grep -v EZREMOVEHEADER

# Basic form of all awk commands
awk search pattern { program actions }

# advanced awk
awk 'BEGIN {init} search1 {actions} search2 {actions} END { final actions }' file

# awk boolean example for matching "(me OR you) OR (john AND ! doe)"
awk '( /me|you/ ) || (/john/ && ! /doe/ )' /path/to/file

# awk - print # of lines in file
awk 'END {print NR,"coins"}' coins.txt

# Sum up gold ounces in column 2, and find out value at $425/ounce
awk '/gold/ {ounces += $2} END {print "value = $" 425*ounces}' coins.txt

# Print the last column of each line in a file, using a comma (instead of space) as a field separator:
awk -F ',' '{print $NF}' filename

# Sum the values in the first column and pretty-print the values and then the total:
awk '{s+=$1; print $1} END {print "--------"; print s}' filename

# functions available
length($0) > 72, toupper,tolower

# count the # of times the word PASSED shows up in the file /tmp/out
cat /tmp/out | awk 'BEGIN {X=0} /PASSED/{X+=1; print $1 X}'

# awk regex operators 
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operators.html
```

Comment: `$0` (particularly used without quotes) will behave badly if the script is in a directory name with spaces, or is a relative path and not in the current directory, or if it was piped into the interpreter, or...

Comment: *If available*, `"$BASH_SOURCE"` is going to be more reliable (more likely to actually provide a usable filename) than `$0`. [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) goes into more detail re: things that can go wrong.

Comment: Why not just use `cat << EOF` ? Also whats the point of `EZREMOVE`?

Comment: thanks @123 - great idea and super simple! I'll change the one liner

Comment: Or `sed '1d'` to not have to rely on a word that doesn't appear in the file.

Comment: You probably want to quote `'EOF'` as the here-doc marker, and add it at the end as well, or you'll get a warning.

Comment: hey... @123 - I ended up going back to my `grep -v` approach as I prefer a one liner, as opposed to something I have to put at the top and bottom of a file. Though I also used the `"$BASH_SOURCE"` approach suggested by [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)

Comment: @BradParks Tbh glenns answer is probably better than mine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea, use `#!/bin/cat` -- this will literally answer the title of your question since the shebang line will be displayed as well.